# Flutter Doctor can't find Android SDK

Tags: android

I recently downloaded Android Studio 4.1 to learn how to code in dart with flutter. the flutter doctor command generates errors, despite the fact that all android sdks are up to date.I have already installed the flutter and dart plugins on Android studio, but same problem. I need help please.
[problem's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyzvv.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by below step,

1. go to -> system environment -> Environment Variables -> system Variable
2. create New Variable Name **ANDROID_HOME** and Value **D:\Androidsdk\tools** (custom android sdk path).
3. concat this path **D:\Androidsdk\platform-tools** in **Path** variable value using ";". (also in system Variable)
4. that's all, Restart the PC to apply changes and try again -- flutter Doctor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, but same problem !